# Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql

Based on what I've read here and on the web, you get this error if you try to store an integer >  [INT's maximum signed value; 2147483647](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). As you can see below, I used `bigint(20)` for `user_id`. So, I don't know why I'm getting this error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_image_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `followers_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `friends_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `statuses_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_name` (`name`),
  KEY `last_update` (`last_update`),
  KEY `screen_name` (`screen_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The php script that handles the insertion:

```
/* Prepare an insert statement */
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, screen_name, name, profile_image_url, created_at, followers_count, friends_count, statuses_count) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("issssiii", $user_id, $screen_name, $name, $profile_image_url, $created_at, $followers_count, $friends_count, $statuses_count);
/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute()
```

FYI: the purpose of this script & table is to store some of Twitter's users data

Comment: Just to double check, does doing a `DESCRIBE users` show user_id as a bigint?

Comment: Also make sure that the value definitely doesn't exist. Try to insert a slightly larger value.

Comment: @Mike Yes. `bigint(20) unsigned` to be exact.

Comment: `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` mysql might be able to handle a 64-bit int, but it won't matter if you're running 32-bit php.

Comment: @Sammitch: It's `PHP_INT_MAX`

Comment: @Sammitch It returned `2147483647`! So, it is a PHP issue?

Comment: @iturki yes and no. yes, in that it's built into the PHP binary. no, in that PHP didn't make you install the 32bit version instead of 64bit.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm on shared hosting & not sure if I have the option to switch between 32bit and 64bit versions. Is there a way you know to solve this under 32bit version?

Comment: @iturki the only way would be to change your application to deal with the userid as a string in PHP and then use `SELECT CAST('$userid' AS UNSIGNED);` in the queries. Though if your hosting provider can't accomodate 64bit PHP in 2014 you may want to consider a new provider.

Comment: @Sammitch Actually I found a simpler way. In `bind_param()`, I changes the char that correspond to `user_id` to `s`. I don't know why mysql didn't through any errors but it works perfectly!

Comment: @Sammitch IIRC, PHP doesn't support 64-bit integer under any environment, also on 64-bit systems (with PHP compiled in 64-bit)

Comment: The reason @iturki's "fix" works is that he's letting PHP treat it as a string and letting MySQL take care of the type conversation, instead of converting it to int in PHP (where the data loss would happen) and then sending that to the database.

Comment: @Qualcuno on my system: `php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'` yields `9223372036854775807`, so... not what you said. That said, certain integers *internal* to PHP are still treated as signed 32bit ints even in 64bit versions, so there's that pitfall as well.

Answer (score 2):

INT has a maximum signed value of 2147483647. Any number greater than that will be truncated to that value. What you need to do is change that column to be a `user_id` varchar(20) unsigned NOT NULL, which will hold strings of up to 20 characters since cards numbers are strings and not actually numbers (you don't do math with the). You also should remove AUTO_INCREMENT as that is not a value you will be incrementing.